# System.Threading.Timer to perform autoupdate

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

While I was trying to implement an auto-update mechanism in my WTF application, I got a runtime error `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.` somewhere in `OnPropertyChanged()` method. I know that WPF applications are STA and I should use a dispatcher, but that still doesn't help :(

In more detail...

I have a service class that has a timer set in constructor to perform an update

```
public VisualNovelService(IVisualNovelRepository repository, TimeSpan autoUpdateInterval)
{
    this._repository = repository;
    this._autoUpdateInterval = autoUpdateInterval;
    this._visualNovels = _repository.GetAll();
    this._autoUpdateTimer = new Timer(
        (state) => Update(),
        null,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), // just so that I can test it, 
        Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);

    this._dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

The object itself, is created in OnStartup method, therefore I believe dispatcher is all fine.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["VisualNovelService"] = new VisualNovelService(new FuwaVNRepository());

    var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    MainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
    MainWindow.Show();
}
```

And here's an update method, which is the terrorist in my code :(

```
public event EventHandler<VisualNovelServiceEventArgs> Updated;

public void Update()
{
    _visualNovels = _repository.GetAll();

    // restart the autoupdate timer
    _autoUpdateTimer.Change(_autoUpdateInterval, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);

    // raise the event
    _dispatcher.Invoke(
        () => Updated(this, new VisualNovelServiceEventArgs(_visualNovels)));
}
```

I do subscribe to the `Updated` event in one method which does nothing, except changing some properties in ViewModel. Therefore I am convinced that threads do not use other threads' objects and I can't figure out why am I getting this error. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error must be at this line -

```
_visualNovels = _repository.GetAll();
```

You are trying to set `_visualNovels` from background thread and i suspect this is binded to some DP in your GUI. So, you should put this call on `UI Dispatcher` as well.

But, i would strongly suggest you to use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) in place of Timer. It is created specifically for WPF.

Comment: Aye, you are right. Damn me, I believe it's high time for break now. I just moved this line inside the dispatcher's invoke method and it all works now. Thank you for your time :)